# Parsing JSON string in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am new in Python so i beg your patience !

In the following output string, i need to get the latest price (determined from timestamp) where type = 'bid'. Please suggest how can i read the output into JSON and read the latest price

```
{"dollar_pound":[
{"type":"ask","price":0.01769341,"amount":1.10113151,"tid":200019988,"timestamp":1515919171},
{"type":"ask","price":0.017755,"amount":3.95681783,"tid":200019987,"timestamp":1515919154},
{"type":"bid","price":0.01778859,"amount":3.7753814,"tid":200019986,"timestamp":1515919152},
{"type":"ask","price":0.017755,"amount":0.01216145,"tid":200019985,"timestamp":1515919147},
{"type":"ask","price":0.017755,"amount":0.05679142,"tid":200019984,"timestamp":1515919135}]}
```

I tried this but didn't worked

```
parsed_json = json.loads(request.text)
price = parsed_json['price'][0]
```

Comment: What did [internet] search results show for "parsing JSON in Python"? Surely you're not the *only* person parsing JSON in Python.. and, once the JSON is parsed, what is the next step? This too (navigating dicts/lists) is probably covered under existing documentation, such as a tutorial.

Comment: The output of HTTP request is shown above. Is there something else you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, tldr; "What did you try? What is 'not working' about *the thing that was tried*?" Nothing was tried? Well, then there is currently *no problem* .. only a task. Good luck solving it!

Comment: parsed_json = json.loads(request.text)
price = parsed_json['price'][0]

Comment: `parsed_json['price']` returns None. Why? How would *iterating a list* (as covered in tutorials) be useful here?

Comment: If you hover over the downvote arrow, the tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort", which is exactly what is the case here. Now, you seem to have located something, so please update your question, but make sure you are specific and that you describe the specific problems you have. Nobody here is going to do your homework for you!

Comment: If i had time to go threw the document i wouldn't had posted this question here. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you want - here's a short script to get the latest price of type "bid":

```py
# Here's a few more test cases for bid prices to let you test out your script
parsed_json = {"dollar_pound":[
{"type":"ask","price":0.01769341,"amount":1.10113151,"tid":200019988,"timestamp":1515919171},
{"type":"ask","price":0.017755,"amount":3.95681783,"tid":200019987,"timestamp":1515919154},
{"type":"bid","price":0.01778859,"amount":3.7753814,"tid":200019986,"timestamp":1515919152},
{"type":"bid","price":0.01542344,"amount":3.7753814,"tid":200019983,"timestamp":1715929152},
{"type":"bid","price":0.023455,"amount":3.7753814,"tid":200019982,"timestamp":1515919552},
{"type":"ask","price":0.017755,"amount":0.01216145,"tid":200019985,"timestamp":1515919147},
{"type":"ask","price":0.017755,"amount":0.05679142,"tid":200019984,"timestamp":1515919135}]}

# To get items of type "bid"
def get_bid_prices(parsed_json):
    return filter(lambda x: x["type"] == "bid", parsed_json)

# Now, we want to get the latest "bid" price, i.e. the largest number in the "timestamp" field
latest_bid_price = max(get_bid_prices(parsed_json["dollar_pound"]), key=lambda x: x["timestamp"])

# Your result will be printed here
print(latest_bid_price) # {"type":"bid","price":0.01542344,"amount":3.7753814,"tid":200019983,"timestamp":1715929152}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all good fellas struggling like me, i would like to share the answer for them.

```
json_data = json.loads (req.text)
for x in json_data['dollar_pound']:
    print (x['price'])
```